# fo:external-graphic That Spans Across Entire Page

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to mimic a design that overall has a 0.375in page margin, but the footer has a graphic that ignores those constraints and stretches across the entire page (left to right).

My first try was to set a `left` attribute -0.375in, but it still starts at the defined left margin of the page.

Should I just zero out left and right margins of the page and simply define the margins for the body region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specifying any margins for the `fo:simple-page-master` would be simplest.

Otherwise, you can set negative margins on an `fo:block` in the `fo:static-content` for your footer.  You would possibly also need to adjust the `fo:region-after/@extent` to compensate for the bottom margin.  E.g., for a 1in high graphic:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="spm" margin="0.375in">
        <fo:region-body/>
        <fo:region-after extent=".625in"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
        <fo:block background-color="red"
        margin="-0.375in" margin-top="0in">a<fo:leader leader-length.optimum="100%"/>b</fo:block></fo:static-content>
```

(The 'a' and 'b' are just to show that the block doesn't extend off the sides of the page.)

Instead of getting `extent` exactly right, you could use `display-align="after"` on the `fo:region-after` to put the bottom of the graphic at the bottom of a taller region.

Comment: The odd part is that now that I've removed the margins to page, the `fo:region-before` will not accept margins even though I applied them.

Comment: You can set margins on `fo:region-body` but not on the 'outer' regions, since they extend inwards from the page-reference-area.  See graphic at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_simple-page-master

Comment: I rearranged the elements to move the section in question into the region-body